# JFrame is visible even though i didn't write: frame.setVisible(true)

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, jframe, frame

So I'm working on a project with JFrames. When the programm starts it creates a JFrame in a Method called "initialThread" and then it sets the bounds, Default Close Operation and the visibility in a Method called "initialize".
When debugging the Method "initialThread", the frame automaticaly becomes visible without me excecuting the "initialize" Method.

**The Code where I run the Methods:**

```
    public void loadPanels(){
    initialThread();
    initialize();
    }
```

**Here's the code with the two Methods i was talking about:**

```
public void initialThread(){
    try {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * set the basic functions and configurations of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: In your initialize method you did write "frame.setVisible(true);"

Comment: @Mano176 yeah I know. The problem is when debugging the Method "initialThread" the frame already appears. IM ONLY DEBUGGING INITIALTHREAD.

Comment: I guess you mean that you put a break point somewhere in `initialThread()` method, and when the execution stops at this break point, the window is already visible. Can you tell us exactly on which line it is placed ?

Comment: @Benoit yeah exactly. I've put the breakpoint where i called the method `initialThread` .

Comment: But according to code you showed us, the frame is not even created at this location, how could it be visible ?

Comment: @Benoit no. It is created. `frame = new JFrame();` , right?

Comment: Yes. But this code is within `initialThread()`, and you have you break point at the call to this method, so it stops **before** it is called.

Comment: @Benoit I've pressed f6 so it moves on after the line `initialThread();` got marked green. So i guess it went inside the Method.

Comment: Then I guess it's something specific to Eclipse, because I was unable to reproduce it (i.e. the frame appears only when `setVisible()` is called) under IntelliJ 2018 and Java 8.

Comment: @Benoit ok yeah. Well thank you a lot for trying to help me. I don't think there's something wrong with my code so i will just move on.